# Oracle SQL Developer - Trying to write a query that I think requires a subquery, I can't seem to find the correct wording

Tags: sql, database, oracle, subquery

I have a school project that requires me to create a database, populate the tables and to then correctly write queries that retrieve certain information. I have one query remaining and it is as follows;

> List the name, strength, species, hoard and gender of all Super Avatars who have more than 2 male children (Mega Avatars) aged 1 or more.  List the output in reverse order of strength and species.

Here is a screenshot of the relevant section of my data model;

[DataModel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmyf5.jpg)

The way it works is that an Avatar evolves into a SuperAvatar and two SuperAvatars can breed a MegaAvatar. They all inherit from the Avatar table and I have a link table that lists the ID for the Father, the Mother and the Child.

Right now, I am stuck of the 'more than 2 children' part of the query. I can list all SuperAvatars that have children, but that is it. Here is a screenshot of the query I have so far and the output (output is as it should be);
[QuerySoFar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnIIC.jpg)

The printed code for the query I have right now is;

```
SELECT DISTINCT sA.AvatarName, sA.Strength_Curr, supSpec.SpeciesName, sA.Hoard, sA.Gender

FROM
Avatar sA, 
Species supSpec,
SuperAvatar super,
MegaAvParents

WHERE 
MegaAvParents.FatherID=super.AvatarID AND super.AvatarID=sA.AvatarID AND sA.SpeciesID=supSpec.SpeciesID
OR MegaAvParents.MotherID=super.AvatarID AND super.AvatarID=sA.AvatarID AND sA.SpeciesID=supSpec.SpeciesID;
```

What I now need is to only show the SuperAvatars that have more than 2 children. I was thinking the best way would to be a COUNT of some sort that counts where MotherID AND/OR? FatherID is more than 2. I guess that would have to be a subquery but whatever iteration of it I try, I get one or more errors. Is this the right way to do the query or can someone point out a better approach?

Thank you and if there is anymore information needed, please let me know!

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  If you are learning SQL, it is even more important to learn the language correctly.

Comment: That's only personal preference, our company's standard is to use only Oracle syntax, which includes + for outer joins, and commas in the From. While it's fine to have a preference of which to use, it's not fair to say to only code one way when the company who hired you may demand knowing how to program otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with this.  I'm being a bit lazy today, but I'm demonstrating how and where you can add a subquery, then test the results of the subquery and return results.  This should give you a starting point.

I am concerned about the "OR" in your where clause.  This will cause you problems.  It look like you may want something like (condition1 AND condition2) OR (condition3 AND condition4).  The parentheses are important.

```
SELECT DISTINCT sA.AvatarName, sA.Strength_Curr, supSpec.SpeciesName, sA.Hoard, sA.Gender, child_count
FROM
(
SELECT sA.AvatarName, sA.Strength_Curr, supSpec.SpeciesName, sA.Hoard, sA.Gender,
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM   <TABLES>
     WHERE  <criteria>) as child_count
FROM
    Avatar sA, 
    Species supSpec,
    SuperAvatar super,
    MegaAvParents
WHERE 
    MegaAvParents.FatherID=super.AvatarID 
    AND super.AvatarID=sA.AvatarID 
    AND sA.SpeciesID=supSpec.SpeciesID
    OR MegaAvParents.MotherID=super.AvatarID -- I'm worried about your OR stmt here, this will give you grief
    AND super.AvatarID=sA.AvatarID 
    AND sA.SpeciesID=supSpec.SpeciesID
) avatar_data
WHERE avatar_data.child_count >= 2;
```